# Are there words with three consecutive occurence of the same letter?

Tags: orthographe, lexique

I know that in French, the word *créée* has 3 times the same consecutive letter, which is *e*. However, I don't think there is any other French word that has the same characteristics.

In English, for example, three-letters word are not authorized and are cut into two words, such as *bee-eater*, etc.

Do you happen to know if there is any other French word that has three consecutive letters like so and if we can find a word in other language that has the same characteristics?

I couldn't find any.
I thought it might be found in German, but I can't think of any word that looks like it.

Comment: In German, there are many composite words that qualify. Just take a noun ending in a double letter and add a related word starting with the same: Schneeeule - snow(y) owl, Schritttempo - walking (literally: step) speed, Betttuch - bed sheet, etc. The third letter was mostly dropped before the [1996 orthogrphy reform](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuerungen_der_deutschen_Rechtschreibreform_von_1996#Dreifachkonsonanten_und_Dreifachvokale), though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Made some queries on my local dictionary.

The same pattern as for *créée* is found in:

- *agréée*
- [*gréée*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gr%C3%A9er)
- *maugréée*
- [*réée*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A9er)
- [*regréée*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/regr%C3%A9er)
- *recréée*
- *supléée*
- [*dégréée*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9gr%C3%A9er)
- *énucléée*
- *guéée*
- [*incréée*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/incr%C3%A9%C3%A9)
- [*congréée*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/congr%C3%A9er)
- *nucléée*
- *procréée*
- *ragréée*
- *récréée*
- [*délinéée*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9lin%C3%A9er)

And two others: *brrr* which is “just” an onomatopoeia, and **désennnuyer*… which is obviously a bug in my dictionary…

Comment: Pour 3 "e" à la suite, [mots-croises.ch en trouve 27 !](http://www.mots-croises.ch/Recherche/complexe.htm?mot=eee&page=1)

Comment: Il faudrait vérifier dans l'œuvre de Shakespeare... On n'écrit pas Hamlet sans caser des e.

Answer (score 2):

With three *e* in a row, I found also **agréée** and **énucléée**, but there could be some few others.

The other vowels, however, don't have any case of the same phenomenon.

But, of course, I didn't consider onomatopeas or made-up words used in [movies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRRrrrr!!!) for example.